# How can I copy the cell as LaTeX code but the look remains as what I typed?

Tags: formatting, latex

I typed this on Mathematica.

[image]

```
Subscript[a, 0] = 1/2 \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n\ odd\), \(\[Infinity]\)]
\*FractionBox[\(8  A\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((n\ \[Pi])\), \(2\)]]\) = 1/2 (8 A)/\[Pi]^2 \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n\ odd\), \(\[Infinity]\)]
\*FractionBox[\(1\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]]\) = 1/2 (8 A)/\[Pi]^2 \[Pi]^2/8 = (A/2)
```

Or the raw input form:

```
Subscript[a, 0] = (1/2)*Sum[(8*A)/(n*Pi)^2, {n*odd, Infinity}] = 
     (1/2)*((8*A)/Pi^2)*Sum[1/n^2, {n*odd, Infinity}] = 
       (1/2)*((8*A)/Pi^2)*(Pi^2/8) = A/2
```

And then I copy the cell as LaTeX I got this:

```
a_0=\frac{1}{2} \sum _{n \text{odd}}^{\infty } \frac{8 A}{(\pi  n)^2}=\frac{(8 A) \sum _{n \text{odd}}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^2}}{2 \pi ^2}=\frac{\pi ^2 (8 A)}{2 \pi ^2 8}=\frac{A}{2}
```

However, if I display this LaTeX code I get a different look with the one I typed above.
 Not that the numerator and demoninator are combined. 
How can I copy the cell as LaTeX code but the look remains as what I typed?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected due to internal transformation and automatic expression rewriting. Since you are using this for display only, you can add

```
\[CenterDot]
```

between the terms you do not want combined which will now give this Latex

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is your input with

```
Subscript[a, 0] = 1/2 \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n\ odd\), \(\[Infinity]\)]
\*FractionBox[\(8  A\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((n\ \[Pi])\), \(2\)]]\) = 
  1/2 (8 A)/\[Pi]^2 \[CenterDot]\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n\ odd\), \(\[Infinity]\)]
\*FractionBox[\(1\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]]\) = 
   1/2 \[CenterDot](8 A)/\[Pi]^2 \[CenterDot]\[Pi]^2/8 = (A/2)
```

Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not know of another way to prevent this. If you can find something better than `\[CenterDot]` you can try it. This gets transformed to `\cdot` in Latex.

`\[CenterDot]`  is in basic typesetting palettes. Under operators

[image]

Comment: thanks, that is nice. `\[CenterDot] ` work but `Dot` doesn't. Would be faster to type  `Dot`  than `\[CenterDot] `.

Comment: @hana you can use Palettes to enter it. One click only.

Comment: The answer is great but I just wonder if there is some way to automate this?
Assume that I have more than 300 expressions so it would be really slow to manually input the center dot.